# solution for credit card acquiring and paypal in the USA for web sites

Tags: c#, web, credit-card

I'm planning to build a web sites that accepts charges in the USA only.

Is there any credit card acquiring software that is easy for a C# ASP.NET web site to implement? Can anyone recommend some?

Are there any rules for saving\encrypting credit cards data in the DB?

Any help would be great...

Comment: Please Please Please DO NOT STORE credit card information in your database.  Please Please Please do some research on what you are required by law to protect.  Please do not be "that guy" who trys to do something wrong and stores information that be used in identity theft or worst.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As pointed out by Albireo, you DO NOT want to store the credit cards in your database. I'd bet Visa/MC/etc probably would not even allow you to, according to your merchant agreement.

First, do you have a merchant account through your bank? You will need one to be able to accept/process credit cards.

You have a couple ways of doing this:

**1. Authorize.NET**

You can sign up directly with Authorize.net (one of the most popular payment gateways available) and use their C# library:

http://www.authorize.net/
http://www.sharpauthorize.com/

The downside is you will have to write a lot more of your billing infrastructure by just using Authorize.NET.

**2. Reoccurring Billing Services**

Use a billing service. Services like Chargify, Recurly, and ChedderGetter offer monthly billing, subscription plans, one-time charges, free trial periods for your customers, coupon codes, etc.

I personally use Chargify. It was incredibly simple to setup. They have an awesome "developer" mode where the entire environment is simulated, allowing you to test registration, credit card declines, etc.

Chargify: http://chargify.com/

The Chargify library for C#/.NET is easy to work with: http://chargify.codeplex.com/

Chargify also has hosted payment pages. This allows you a custom branded page, hosted on the Chargify website, that will handle your registrations. Now, you don't even need to interface with a payment gateway. Simply redirect your users to this page and Chargify will handle collecting the payment details: http://chargify.com/features/branded-payment-websites/

With Chargify, you will need to independently get an Authorize.net account and a merchant account with your bank.

BrainTree has become very popular as of late, and a lot of very respected startups are using them. BrainTree seems to offer the complete package, of both reoccurring billing as well as merchant services.

http://www.braintreepaymentsolutions.com/

I'd recommend using either BrainTree or Chargify. You will save an enormous amount of time not writing your billing infrastructure. It allows you to focus on your core product, and it gives your users assurances that their credit card data is protected.

Answer (score 3):

### Do not store credit card data in your database, unless you want to face hell if you get hacked. Even if encrypted.

Usually banks provide a service where you can redirect the user on a bank's page, the user pays there and the bank sends you a payment confirmation (much like PayPal). This way you'll never ever handle sensitive informations.

I'm sorry I can't point you to any of such service, but I never had to work with an American bank.

Comment: I thought a little more emphasis was warranted for this situation :)

Answer (score 0):

Try out [BrainTree Payment Solutions](http://www.braintreepaymentsolutions.com/).

Disclaimer: I have never used them, nor do I know anyone that has; but they seem to be very developer friendly.