# How to Integrate payment facility(visa/Mastercard) in web application

Tags: asp.net, payment-gateway

We are building some shopping Website.Payment option we want to provide are:
 1.Master card
 2.Visa
 3.PayPal
How to Integrate this facility in our application?
Is there any API for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote an answer to a similar question yesterday. It explains some of your options: [solution for credit card acquiring and paypal in the USA for web sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597087/solution-for-credit-card-acquiring-and-paypal-in-the-usa-for-web-sites/5597731#5597731)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>PayPal [has an API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_reference). MasterCard and Visa are not payment providers so they don't have APIs, but there are payment processors that you can work with such as [WorldPay](http://www.worldpay.com/) or your bank's Merchant Account provider, if they let you have one.</strike>

Comment: MasterCard now has a variety of APIs in the works: https://developer.mastercard.com/portal/display/api/Payments