# PHP:transaction using paypal,Master card and Visa card

Tags: php

I am creating a PHP website. Here a portion is customer can pay to website owner from paypal,visa and master card(debit/credit). If transaction successful customer will get a confirmation notification and website owner will also get a confirmation notification.

I did not a work like online transaction before!! What is the best and secure way to do this?

Any help or source code is highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Paypal](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/05/getting-started-with-the-paypal-api/) API.

Answer (score 1):

for paypal you need to Set up a business account with PayPal and read the documentation for their  [Express Checkout integration.](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECGettingStarted)

[for visa and mastercard please check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597087/solution-for-credit-card-acquiring-and-paypal-in-the-usa-for-web-sites/5597731#5597731)

Comment: Thank you.What for Visa and Master Card?